# MySQL Id columns

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am working on a project that is an upgrade of an existing system.

The existing DB structure must be kept intact as there is a system reading the same DB that will be used ontop of the new system.

I am building a new CMS / Management system using a PHP framework that expects so see all DB table autoincrement ID field named simply "id" - I do not want to modify the PHP deal with anything other that "id" as this field name - trust me it will be a massive task.

The existing DB has non standard Autoincrement ID field naming, eg:
"iBmsId" -shcema: i=INT Bms = the name of the table, Id = ID....

Is there anything I can do to the DB itself to make a duplicate of the "iBmsId" column, to create a matched column called simply "id" that has the corresponding INT values? This way my new system will function as expected without having to do a serious re-write, and at the same time still have the existing system able to communicate with the DB?

Comment: you can use an INSERT trigger on iBmsId which inserts the inserted value in you so called 'id' column

Comment: Does the new system only read the `id` value or does it modify it as well?

Comment: the new system will be entering new entries, the autoincrement will take care of the numbering of ID. The ID value should not be changed by the system.

Comment: @Codegeek, INSERT TRIGGER seems more like what I am thinking, can this be done in 2 directions, ie insert new record, auto-increment col is given an ID and then copied to the ID column, and visa-versa?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you can just use VIEW :)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

View in dbms is like a virtual table (unless it's materialized). Views add a new abstraction layer which can support independency between how you use db and how it's implemented. It can also increase security for example by hiding some fields or making view readonly.

*Notice:* In order to add view transparently you can rename origin table and create the View with origin table name. This let's you avoid modifications in existing code.

You can read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html) how to create updatable and insertable view (which can behave as normal table).

Answer (score 0):

If only one system at a time is modifying the value, then you can use a view:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*, iBMid as id
    from table t;
```

Presumably, an auto-incremented value is not going to be updated, so this should be safe.  However, keep in mind that:

> To be more specific, a view is not updatable if it contains any of the following:
>
> . . .
>
> - Multiple references to any column of a base table.

This could affect other columns that you might want to treat the same way.